# Select value of element which is referenced by other

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have (this is an example) the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <list>
    <toot id="1">
      <value>A</value>
    </toot>
    <toot id="2">
      <value>B</value>
    </toot>
    <toot id="3">
      <value>C</value>
    </toot>
    <toot id="4">
      <value>D</value>
    </toot>
  </list>
  <otherlist>
    <foo>
      <value ref="2" />
    </foo>
    <foo>
      <value ref="3" />
    </foo>
  </otherlist>
</body>
```

And the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="otherlist"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="otherlist">
    <xsl:for-each select="foo">
      <result>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="/body/list/toot[@id=value/@ref]/value" /></value><!-- This is the important -->
        <ref><xsl:value-of select="value/@ref" /></ref>
      </result>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result when it make/transform the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <value/>
  <ref>2</ref>
</result>
<result>
  <value/>
  <ref>3</ref>
</result>
```

And the problem is that  is empty. What I wanna get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <value>B</value>
  <ref>2</ref>
</result>
<result>
  <value>C</value>
  <ref>3</ref>
</result>
```

I think the problem is the XPath `/body/list/toot[@id=value/@ref]/value` specifically the condition `[@id=value/@ref]`. Is not correct it? How to use a value of other element witch is reference by the current one?

Comment: Please, the one that down vote my question explain why have you done it.

Comment: Because someone got offended by the word "boob" and [is complaining on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284312/use-of-profanity-in-code-blocks)... That's sad, I know. :(

Comment: @AndréDaniel Thank you for the information, I haven't notice its use (I'm not English). I hope, he can come and see that it was a simple mistake and remove its downvote.

Comment: I'm personally fine with profanity as long as it's not used on purpose to offend the site's visitors, but looks like some people are just too sensitive...

Comment: I'm offended by the word 'toot' because it's like 'tot' which makes 'dead' in German. 'Boob' was in no way offensive to me because it looks like 'Bob' which is a regular male name. Please edit your code and change <boob> to <luucy>. It should make even genderists happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the problem is in XPath where the context is changing so you are actually looking for `toot` element which has `@id` attribute and `value` child with `@ref` attribute (which is actually child of foo) and these two are equal.

You can employ current() function to make it working

```
<xsl:value-of select="/body/list/toot[@id=current()/value/@ref]/value"/>
```

Or you can store value of `@ref` into a variable and use this variable in predicate

```
<xsl:variable name="tmpRef" select="value/@ref" />
<xsl:value-of select="/body/list/toot[@id=$tmpRef]/value"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer so speedily. I'm a little new with XPath :).